# W3C validating clickable content box

Tags: html, css, validation, w3c, w3c-validation

Is it possible to create a clickable box that validates (W3C)? In the clickable box I need list elements and paragraphs.

**This don't validate:**

```
<a href="http://www.test.com">
   <p>My paragraph</p>
   <ul>
      <li>My content item</li>
   </ul>
</a>
```

**This validates but don't solve the problem (very ugly):**

```
<a href="http://www.test.com">
   <span class="p">My paragraph</span>
   <span class="ul">
      <span class="li">My content item</span>
   </span>
</a>
```

**This validates but disables the middle mouse click to open page in a new tab.**

```
<div onclick="window.location='http://www.test.com'">
   <p>My paragraph</p>
   <ul>
      <li>My content item</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried option 1 with the HTML5 doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html>` - it should validate.